# NullPointerException when using Spring RestTemplate in Android

Tags: android, spring, azure, nullpointerexception, resttemplate

I'm using a Spring 3 MVC Server that is hosted on Windows Azure, and am using this to provide users with interaction both through a web browser and an Android device. All code is written in Java.

When I interact with the server through the browser, everything is OK, and when interacting with it using Android it works OK if the server is run as localhost. However, when I interact with the Azure hosted server using the Android client, I randomly (but always eventually) get a `NullPointerException`, so sometimes the code runs fine but eventually this will show up. Exactly where I get the `NullPointer` changes, but it is always during a HTTP call using `RestTemplate`.

Another strange thing, when running the Android app in debug, the code will run to some arbitrary point in the code (still crashing at a `RestTemplate` call), but the stack trace for the `NullPointerException` will point to a call made earlier on.

The general code I make for a call is similar to the following:

```
 private class ChangeDirectory extends AsyncTask< String, Void, Boolean >
{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... directoryName) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( new StringHttpMessageConverter() );

        String url = "http://" + Constants.DNS +"/ui/android/cloud/change_directory";

        restTemplate.put(url, 
                         directoryName[0]);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the stack trace looks like:

```
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:62)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:46)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:476)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:438)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.put(RestTemplate.java:364)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.artmaps.im.activity.HomeActivity$ChangeDirectory.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:192)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.artmaps.im.activity.HomeActivity$ChangeDirectory.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:1)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-05 11:32:05.081: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  ... 5 more
```

which points to the `restTemplate.put(url, directoryName[0]);`  call

I've tried putting in statements on the server side, and when these `NullPointer`s are thrown it appears that the request isn't received by the server as the statements aren't reached.

Any help as to the cause of the `NullPointerException` would be very much appreciated as i'm pretty confused by this, especially as sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't

EDIT:
After looking around some more it appears there is a bug in the Spring for Android framework, as per https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ANDROID-102

This helps a little, but still doesn't explain why it works sometimes and only fails when interacting with the server based in Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought I'd post what I found in case anybody else gets stuck on this. It turned out to be somehow related to the bug I posted in the edit to my question.

I got around this by removing the Spring `RestTemplate` calls and using `DefaultHttpClient` instead.

E.g. changing this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add( new StringHttpMessageConverter() );

    String url = "http://" + Constants.DNS +"/ui/android/cloud/change_directory";

    restTemplate.put(url, 
                     directoryName[0]);
    return true;
```

to this:

```
String url = "http://" + Constants.DNS +"/ui/android/cloud/change_directory";
        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(url);
            putRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(directoryName[0]));
            client.execute(putRequest);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: A good workaround but how it is not to be able to use spring android for that. Is it maintained, no one did anything for this bug...https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ANDROID-102

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the bug report. It appears it has now been fixed (from version 1.0.1).

Comment: The bug is still there in the 1.0.1 version, but you can work around this by: restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()); With this, you will use the 'old' HttpComponents which does not have this bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error, chances are that you have a problem with Gzip compression : Here is work around, tested on ICS & JB, but that should work everywhere :

Inspired from  http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate() {
        @Override
        protected ClientHttpRequest createRequest( URI url, HttpMethod method ) throws IOException {
            ClientHttpRequest request = super.createRequest( url, method );
            HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
            headers.setAcceptEncoding( ContentCodingType.GZIP );

            return request;
        }
    };

    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO ) {
        System.setProperty( "http.keepAlive", "false" );
    }

    try {
        long httpCacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        File httpCacheDir = new File( getCacheDir(), "http" );
        Class.forName( "android.net.http.HttpResponseCache" ) //
                .getMethod( "install", File.class, long.class )//
                .invoke( null, httpCacheDir, httpCacheSize );
    } catch ( Exception httpResponseCacheNotAvailable ) {
        Ln.v( "Http cache disabled" );
    }
```

Where Ln is RoboGuice Log library.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while implementing a custom `ClientHttpRequestFactory` extending `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`. I would also get random NullPointerExceptions.

The solution was to extend from `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` instead of `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and perform the necessary logic in the `postProcessHttpRequest(HttpUriRequest httpRequest)` method.

Here's a quick example of a customized `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` accesing and setting the user-agent field in the header:

```
public class CustomHTTPRequestFactory extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {

    public CustomHTTPRequestFactory() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void postProcessHttpRequest(HttpUriRequest httpRequest) {
        httpRequest.setHeader("User-Agent", "my-user-agent-string");
        super.postProcessHttpRequest(httpRequest);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved upgrading to 1.0.1 Spring Framework and using String.format with **Locale** for the URL and **ClientHttpFactory**.

```
private class ChangeDirectory extends AsyncTask< String, Void, Boolean >
{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... directoryName) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true); // default converters
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        String url = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"http://%s/ui/android/cloud/change_directory", Constants.DNS);

        restTemplate.put(url, directoryName[0]);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I hope this works for you.